# How to Extract Date and time ( in Hours, Minutes, Seconds, DayofWeek, Day, Month) from DateTimePicker? WPF extended toolkit by Xceed

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, xceed

I have WPF Extended Toolkit 3.5.0 (by Xceed), I'm using DateTimePicker control from here. I want to know that how to get selected Values of Hours, Minutes, Seconds, DayofWeek, Day, Month separately by DateTimePicker.
Before this I was using telerik DateTimePicker Control Here I was using this approach to get these values

```
hours= DTPicker.SelectedTime.Value.Hours;
minutes= DTPicker.SelectedTime.Value.Minutes;
seconds= DTPicker.SelectedTime.Value.Seconds;
//for date
dayofweek= DTPicker.SelectedDate.Value.DayOfWeek;
day= DTPicker.SelectedDate.Value.Day;
month= DTPicker.SelectedDate.Value.Month;
```

But I couldn't find SelectedDate/SelectedTime/SelectedValue properties here.
Thanks

Comment: It has a Value property that returns a DateTime?.

Comment: I want to extract further values as well which i mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Value` property returns a `DateTime?`:

```
DateTime? value = dateTimePicker.Value;
if (value.HasValue)
{
    hours = value.Value.TimeOfDay.Hours;
    minutes = value.Value.TimeOfDay.Minutes;
    seconds = value.Value.TimeOfDay.Seconds;
    //for date
    dayofweek = value.Value.DayOfWeek;
    day = value.Value.Day;
    month = value.Value.Month;
}
```

You could basically just replace `SelectedTime` by `Value` in your current code.

Comment: @BilalTahir: What? `Value` returns a `DateTime` so of course there is. If `dateTimePicker` is a  `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.DateTimePicker`, this code compiles just fine. What control are you really using...?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have named your Toolkit DateTiemPicker as DTPicker.

```
<toolkits:DateTimePicker Value="{Binding LastUpdated}" Format="FullDateTime" Width="200" Height="30" Name="DTPicker"/>
```

Then you can get all the value you need as below.

```
var seledtedDateTime = DTPicker.Value;
if (seledtedDateTime.HasValue)
{
    var hours = seledtedDateTime.Value.Hour;
    var minutes = seledtedDateTime.Value.Minute;
    var seconds = seledtedDateTime.Value.Second;
    var dayofweek = seledtedDateTime.Value.DayOfWeek;
    var day = seledtedDateTime.Value.Day;
    var month = seledtedDateTime.Value.Month;
}
```